# Why is it necessary to create non-parametric constructor for an object to be bound with Solr Response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-binding, solr, solrj

I'm using `solrj` in my project and following [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/using-solrj.html#java-object-binding) tutorial, I created an object class

```
public class Student {
    @Field String id;

    public Student(String studentId) {
        this.id = studentId;
    }

    //setter and getter methods here

}
```

And used the following code to retrieve data from Solr and bind the response to `Student` object

```
final SolrClient client = getSolrClient();
final SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
query.addField("id");

final QueryResponse response = client.query("collection-name", query);
final List<Student> students = response.getBeans(Student.class);
```

I'm getting an error at last line. `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Could not instantiate object of class Student`

But, when I add `public Student() { }` constructor to Student class, It works fine. My question is, why didn't it work in the first case or why is it necessary to create a non-parametric constructor here?

Comment: How would SolrJ know what value to map to your constructor? Since it'll have to create the object before assigning values, it won't be able to do that if there's no way it can construct the object without additional information.

Answer (score 0):

In all solrj ref guides, there is an example and it has empty constructor, but there is no description for that. I think the api calls empty constructor before fetch data and fills fields one by one.